# Build Errors [Roslyn End User Preview]

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

I installed the End User Preview, cloned the source code and then followed the directions in the 'Building, Testing, and Debugging' section exactly. Unfortunately, when building the Roslyn.sln from a command line, I get two errors which are breaking it:

```
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Roslyn.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Roslyn.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\Core\CodeAnalysisTest\CodeAnalysisTest.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Test\Utilities\TestUtilities.csproj" (default target) (5) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\CSharp\Source\CSharpCodeAnalysis.csproj" (default target) (7) ->
(GenerateSyntaxModel target) -> 
  C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Toolset.Open\Targets\GenerateCompilerInternals.targets(51,5): error MSB3073: The command ""..\..\..\..\Binaries\Debug\CSharpSyntaxGenerator.exe" Syntax\Syntax.xml obj\Debug\Syntax.xml.Generated.cs" exited with code 3. [C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\CSharp\Source\CSharpCodeAnalysis.csproj]


"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Roslyn.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\Core\CodeAnalysisTest\CodeAnalysisTest.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Test\Utilities\TestUtilities.csproj" (default target) (5) ->
"C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\VisualBasic\Source\BasicCodeAnalysis.vbproj" (default target) (13) ->
  C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Tools\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Toolset.Open\Targets\GenerateCompilerInternals.targets(51,5): error MSB3073: The command ""..\..\..\..\Binaries\Debug\VBSyntaxGenerator.exe" Syntax\Syntax.xml obj\Debug\Syntax.xml.Generated.vb" exited with code 3. [C:\Users\Nate\Source\Repos\roslyn\Src\Compilers\VisualBasic\Source\BasicCodeAnalysis.vbproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:08.84
```

The entire build log can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10598848)

Any insight into what I may be overlooking would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check that the generator mentioned actually exists?  There have been a couple of reports of Antivirus software quarantining them because they are not signed, but copyright Microsoft.

Comment: Try building the `CSharpCodeAnalysis` and `BasicCodeAnalysis` projects manually.  Apparently the build hasn't detected that some dependent projects have built yet. Your log indicates that the `CSharpSyntaxGenerator` and `VisualBasicSyntaxGenerator` tools projects are building without problems.